# How can I resume Agisoft Python API processing from the last checkpoint?

Tags: python

Is there any functionality in Agisoft that allows the process to resume from last checkpoint?

I am currently using Agisoft Python API 1.8.5 to process a large dataset of images. The processing takes a long time, and I would like to be able to resume the process from the last checkpoint if I need to stop the process for any reason.

Is there any functionality in Agisoft that allows me to do this? If so, how can I use it?

Thank you for your help.

i have tried doc.save() and checkpoint creation

````
project.open("my_project.psx")

doc = project.document

doc.save()

doc.save(os.path.join(project_folder, 'checkpoint_1.psx'))```
````